# xdebug on OS X partially working (e.g., prints stack trace in terminal but not browser). 

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I'm trying to get xdebug working on my Mac. I'm using OS 10.6 with the built-in versions of Apache (2.2.1) and PHP (5.3.8). I followed the "[tailored installation instructions](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php)" on the xdebug website, which basically consisted of these steps:

1. Build xdebug (version 2.1.3) from source
2. Move `xdebug.so` to `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`
3. Add to php.ini: 
   zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
4. Restart the webserver.

From what I understand, that should be it. I know most people use xdebug with an IDE like PHPEclipse, but it doesn't sound like that's necessary just to get debugging output on the page. And a lot of old instructions involve installing MAMP, but it looks like that's no longer necessary.

**Signs xdebug is working:** When I run `php -m` and `phpinfo()` I get the expected information on xdebug. In scripts I'm able to call functions like `xdebug_is_enabled()` (returns 1) and `xdebug_get_function_stack()` (returns the stack).

**Ways xdebug is not working:** The main reason I installed xdebug was to get a stack trace when there's an error, and that's not happening. According to [this documentation page](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace), I should get a stack trace as long as `display_errors` is set to On in php.ini, (which it is). I've tried code that should evoke a warning (e.g., `echo(hello)`) as well as code that produces a fatal error (e.g., `$x->awesomefunction()` when $x isn't an object). Neither one produces any xdebug output, and the fatal error just causes the page to die silently. The test code given in the documentation I linked to also produces nothing.

**UPDATE:** It turns out that if I run a script with a fatal error from the terminal, I do get a stack trace from xdebug. However, it's still not showing up when I run the script from a browser

**Also, regular error reporting is now broken:** Previously, I'd get error output by including the commands:

```
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
```

Now, putting those lines in my script doesn't produce any error reporting either. (in the browser. It does cause errors to be shown when I run the script from the terminal.)

So, what's wrong here? Did I leave something out of the xcode installation? Do I have a setting hanging around somewhere else on my system, suppressing errors? I've tried everything I can think of, but I'd be happy to test any ideas you have.

Comment: Have you tried to run your tests in console instead of browser to look for errors?

Comment: Interesting! I do get a stack trace from xdebug when I run a script that produces a fatal error from the console, but I still don't when I run it in the browser. I'll update my question with that...

Comment: Have you considered using the pre-build LIIP PHP packages?  They incorporate xDebug and I've found them very easy to use and configure. http://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: @GordonM I wish I'd known about that a couple of days ago, when I started futzing with this. If I can't fix this problem, I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several more hours of thrashing, I discovered that one of my test files actually was including another file that set display_errors to 0. The other test file was straight off of the xdebug site, but I think that at the time I was using it I'd introduced some other config error that prevented it from working properly. I'm truly embarrassed! Let this be today's object lesson in the importance of systematic, repeatable tests during debugging. On the bright side, xdebug is now working like a peach.

To summarize, the series of steps that worked was:

1. Build xdebug (version 2.1.3) from source
2. Move xdebug.so to /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
3. Add to php.ini: zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
4. **Add to php.ini: display_errors = On**
5. Restart the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on console and not on browser, it's probably a xdebug configuration issue.

I'm not a Mac user, but on Ubuntu there are 2 different php.ini files, one for console and one for apache. If that's the case for Mac also, you can check if xdebug is enabled and properly set up in both php.ini files.

Also you can check the xdebug settings mentioned in the [guide](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace).

Comment: Apache is definitely using the same php.ini file I'm editing. For example, I'm able to use the function xdebug_is_enabled() in a script. If I comment out the line in php.ini that loads the xdebug extension, then that function causes a fatal error in both the browser and the terminal.